# Beginner MySQL query build for find and replace

Tags: mysql

I'm just getting into SQL and need a hand with some of the basics.

I'm trying to write a query that will allow me to find values between range in one column of a table and replace all values in that range with a single value that I would specify with an UPDATE or REPLACE function. 
I've gotten as far as

```
SELECT *
FROM (Table_A)
WHERE Column BETWEEN #a and #b
ORDER by Column desc
```

but I get back 0 results even though I know there are tons of values between #a and #b.

Comment: What is the kind of the Column? int, varchar ... ?

Answer (score 1):

Select with BETWEEN

```
   SELECT * FROM Table_A WHERE column BETWEEN 10 AND 30
```

Update

```
update Table_A set column = 'NEW_VALUE' where column BETWEEN 10 AND 30
```

Replace 
// string hallo2 -> will be change to hallo3

```
update Table_A set column = replace(column, "2", "3") where column BETWEEN 10 AND 30
```